# Is there any option at Pytorch autograd function for these problem?

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient, tensor, autograd

Sorry for the vague title because I don't know exactly how to ask the question.

I'm using pytorch's autograd function right now and I'm struggling with the results I don't understand.

In common sense, the grad calculated by the loss is how far each parameter should go in the direction where the loss is minimized. Because it doesn't make sense for the value to change just because the scale has changed.

It means  $$ grad(loss) = 5*grad(loss* \frac 1 5) $$

But my actual result doesn;t. So

[formulation explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w6ev.png)

And this is my actual code:)

```
from torch.autograd import grad
train_loss = loss(models(adaptation_data), adaptation_labels)
grads = grad(train_loss , models.parameters(),create_graph=True)
grads_02 = grad(train_loss*0.2 , models.parameters(),create_graph=True)
grads[-1] == grads_02[-1] * 5
#result : False
```

[the whole code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INo1j.png)

Maybe I'm doing something wrong or there is an option for this for the grad function, but can anyone tell me? please

Answer (score 1):

Your code screenshot shows that the two tensors are different due to floating point truncation error. Do not compare them with `==` sign, use [isclose()](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.isclose.html#torch.isclose) function instead

```
torch.isclose(grads[-1], grads_02[-1] * 5)
```